# Entity Framework 5 ASP.Net Implement Interface As Model Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Using MVC4, Entity Framework 5, I would ideally like every type to utilise an interface,

So I have my interfaces, one with a 'navigation' property to the other;

interface Ifoo has:

```
IUser User {get; set;}
int UserID {get; set;}
```

Lets say IUser only has UserID and UserName properties.

When implementing the Ifoo interface in a type, I use

```
public Iuser User {get; set;}
public UserID {get; set;}
```

Then, using EF5, I eager load the navigation propert, using my User type, which implements IUser:

```
db.Foo.where(x => x.id == id).Include(x => x.User)
```

But It tells me that:

A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Dal.Foo' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'User'.

However, If I change both the interfaces to implement the type directly, it works fine.

Is there a way around this so I can utilise interfaces?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of this QA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747442/error-when-using-interfaces-for-entity-framework-4-2-entities

Answer (score 0):

I know this can be done using partial classes. so you can either use a partial class and ignore the interface, or just implement the interface in a partial class then inherit that.
I recommend looking into T4 templates.