# C# Entity Framework Code first Foreign Key in Interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I have a problem.  I have one to many relation in a database and I want to use interfaces.

How I can realize this?

```
[Table("CashRegister")]
public class CashRegister : ICashRegister
{
    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double Sum { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Guid CurrencyId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("CurrencyId")]
    public ICurrency Currency { get; set; }       
}
public interface ICashRegister 
{
    [Key]
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    Guid CurrencyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CurrencyId")]
    ICurrency Currency { get;set; }
    double Sum { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [error when using interfaces for Entity Framework (4.2) entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747442/error-when-using-interfaces-for-entity-framework-4-2-entities) (Still applies)

Comment: Unforutnately, @GertArnold is right.  I believe that EF7 will support Dependency Injection, however and will allow you to do define concrete mappings to interfaces...  But that's a ways out yet.