# Using Interfaces With DbSet, Possible with EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-core-2.0

[Back in EF 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8747442) it was not possible. Is it possible to use interfaces with a `DbSet` in EF6 or EF Core?

```
public class LfSp3Ctx : DbContext, ILfSp3Ctx
{
    public DbSet<ILfSp3Project> ProjectSE { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Never been possible and still isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, but it requires some trickery.  EF will only instantiate DbSet types directly.  Thus, you'd have to create your own interface that wraps/exposes all the DbSet methods you want and the actual implementation takes the DbSet instance in its constructor.  Then on the DbContext class, you have to do something like this:

```
IDbSet<DigimonEntity> DigimonRepository => new DbSetRepository<DigimonEntity>(this.Digimons);

DbSet<DigimonEntity> Digimons { get; set; }

public class DbSetRepository<T> : IDbSet<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> _set;
    public DbSetRepository(DbSet<T> set) => _set = set;

    public Type ElementType => ((IQueryable<T>)_set).ElementType;
    public Expression Expression => ((IQueryable<T>)_set).Expression;
    public IQueryProvider Provider => ((IQueryable<T>)_set).Provider;
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<T>)_set).GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<T>)_set).GetEnumerator();

    void IDataStoreRepositoryWrite<T>.Add(T entity) => _set.Add(entity);
    void IDataStoreRepositoryWrite<T>.Update(T entity) => _set.Update(entity);
    void IDataStoreRepositoryWrite<T>.Delete(T entity) => _set.Remove(entity);

    Task IDataStoreRepositoryWrite<T>.AddAsync(T entity, CancellationToken token) => _set.AddAsync(entity, token);
}
```

Something like this.  Mine is kind of specific to the implementation I was trying to pull off at the time. :)

Comment: In your example you're not using the interface with the dbset as asked in the question, am I wrong? You're using the interface IDbSet but the question was if one can use an interface as type of the DbSet<T>

Comment: Ah, you are right. Though, technically you could by wrapping it like I show here. You would need a real DbSet that implements the type that would be passed into a wrapper that would expose the interface. It would then use that DbSet implementation indirectly... But not sure it would really gain you that much.